# drm/kms: Limit graphics memory usage of process

Tags: graphics, resources, kms, drm

Is there a way to limit the amount of graphics resources allocated by a process in the DRM/KMS subsystem, similar to the way one can limit system memory consumption with rlimits and cgroups? Is there a way to create a render node with such limits?

If not, is there a way to do so in userspace, perhaps by virtualizing the graphics device?

I apologize if my question involves any fundamental misconceptions, and please let me know if it does.